# What are the URLs for devel generated images in CCK fields?

Tags: 7, entities, debugging

I generated a few nodes with Devel. When I do a `krumo($node)`, the CCK field consisting of an image, does not have a filename. `$field_name['und'][0][filename]` is a string of 0 characters. I only get this: `$field_name['und'][0]['uri'] = public:///garbledImageName.tmp.png`. How do I use this? What function does Drupal use, to convert this public:/// URI into a complete image path? And in the future, can I count on custom created modules to also have the 'uri' value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal uses the [`file_create_url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) function for this:

> Creates a web-accessible URL for a stream to an external or local file.

Code example:

```
$url = file_create_url($field_name['und'][0]['uri']);
```